# Scope of an imported variable in ionic v3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Today I had a following doubt about what is the real scope of an imported variable in Ionic v3
In my case I am using a constants file, I import it in a variable but I can not use it in my html.
In order to use it, first I have to assign it to another variable.

I leave an example of code.
*Constants.ts*

```
export const HELLO_WORLD= 'Hello World!';
export const HELLO_EVERYONE= 'Hello Everyone!';
export const HELLO_PLANET= 'Hello Planet!';
```

On my page:
*example.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as Constants from '../../providers/utils/Constants';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-example',
  templateUrl: 'example.html',
})
export class ExamplePage {

  public data = Constants;

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ExamplePage');
    console.log(this.data.HELLO_WORLD); // Output: "Hello World!"
    console.log(this.data); // Output: Object with constants
    console.log(Constants); // Output: Object with constants
  }
}
```

*example.html* **(Work!)**

```
<h3>Result "data.HELLO_WORLD"</h3>
<p>{{data.HELLO_WORLD}}</p>
```

*example.html* **(Don't Work!)**
Console output: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property

```
<h3>Result "Constants.HELLO_WORLD"</h3>
<p>{{Constants.HELLO_WORLD}}</p>
```

I would like to know why from my example.html I can not access my Constants variable.
Thank you very much for your time

Comment: This is relative to Angular.
Only the global variables of the page can be accessed from the view (html). The view does not have access to the imports.